# How can i get something like this without HTF Repainting

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Please copy and run the code below in your pine editor and see how the signals appear, I dont know how to explain it with words.
After running it, please how can I write an indicator that display signals in that manner and that won't repaint from the higher timeframe? Notice how ranges were avoided.
If I add [1] after ta.rsi(close, 1), it will give some false signals because the HTF bar has to close first.
Here is the code example:

```
//@version=5
indicator("Non-Repainting Example", overlay=true)

rsi_ = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "60", ta.rsi(close, 1))

buy = ta.crossover (rsi_, 50)
sell = ta.crossunder (rsi_, 50)

plotshape(buy, style=shape.labelup, location=location.belowbar, size=size.small, color=color.green)
plotshape(sell, style=shape.labeldown, location=location.abovebar, size=size.small, color=color.red)
```

Comment: Have you tried using `barmerge.lookahead_on`? Also, not everyone will understand what you mean by *"ranges were avoided"*. It would be helpful if you added a screenshot showing where they are not being plotted and where you expected them to plot.

Comment: Thanks for your support @RakeshPoluri. What I meant by ranges were avoided is that signals were in a zigzag manner regardless of consolidation.